# optimization with adaptive regularization

Tags: optimization

I have confusion over simple optimization problem with a soft regularization term. Say I have an objective function in the form:

```
                                   E=f(x)+wg(x)
```

where f(x) is a similarity term and g(x) is a regularization term, and w is the weight to the regularization term.

There are methods where w can be adaptively changed. For example, if the objective function keeps decreasing with iterations, I consider my model is updated in the right direction and we decrease w. Or vice verse, if objective function is increased, I increase w.

My problem is that the change of w affects the value of the objective function. Now if I am going to use the change of objective value as a standard to adaptively change w, it would not be plausible. What is the correct way of applying this "adaptive weight of regularization term"?

Thank you.